# Unable to show full screen youtube video in webview

Tags: android

I am simply loading youtube link in webview. Video is playing perfectly but youtube full screen option is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full screen option not available when loading YouTube video in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275299/full-screen-option-not-available-when-loading-youtube-video-in-webview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView with an embedded youtube video, full screen button freezes video](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14763483/11683)

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks alot man