# Javascript Google Maps api within webview Android. how to get full screen map?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-webview, fullscreen

I'm developing a webapp and mobile phone apps (Android and IOS) using webview to include the webapp and native code to improove user experience and add other features with mobile app.

In the webapp i make use of javascript maps api v3 and in mobile apps google maps are working well using webview and javascript api. 
Only trouble is that in Android when i try to open the map in full screen mode it doesn't show. I would like to avoid writing millions of rows just to get a map in fullscreen mode so i would like to avoid native api and intent cause I send eventsto server when user clicks or drags markers. 
At the beginning i was not able to let maps show full screen button in Android webview. I managed to show button using this:

```
 myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
         @Override
         public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback){ super.onShowCustomView(view, callback)}
```

The real trouble is that clicking on full screen button it open a new View showing just the app title and nothing more.

Anyone managed to get a google maps using javascript api and webview to show in fullscreen mode?

I found the solution thanks to [ameya-bonkinpelliwar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813802/8179735)
this answer (not related to maps but to full screen management)

Allowed me to get full screen map working